# what is .mys.utf8.sql extension?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
<install>
 <sql>
     <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/mysql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
     <file driver="sqlazure" charset="utf8">sql/sqlazure/install.sqlazure.utf8.sql</file>
 </sql>
</install>

<uninstall>
 <sql>
     <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/mysql/uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
     <file driver="sqlazure" charset="utf8">sql/sqlazure/uninstall.sqlazure.utf8.sql</file>
 </sql>
</uninstall>

<update> 
 <schemas>
    <schemapath type="mysql">sql/mysql/updates</schemapath> 
  <schemapath type="sqlazure">sql/sqlazure/updates</schemapath> 
 </schemas> 
</update>
```

I will like to know if i can export my DB in Phpmyadmin to one format like this or something than i can read with xml

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet really contains little data at all and nothing usable to recreate your database. It's not really an export of your database, it's a portion of code that tells you (or some program) where to find the SQL file to create (or uninstall, or update) your database.

I'm curious about where this file came from, because it's not a format that MySQL can read, so it has to come from some other program as that program's native format. To make a file like that, you'd have to use whatever program made it. phpMyAdmin can do an XML format, but it doesn't look like this.

Also, I've never seen a `.mys.utf8.sql` extension, but my guess is that it's a file containing SQL commands that's encoded as UTF8. Most files I'm familiar with only have one extension, so that's a new one for me.